# how to use php regular expression

Tags: php, regex, string

I wanted to count asterisks from a string starting with **foo** 'foo*arbaz*luj*abaz*lewis*bazbazlewbaz' and i should be able to count asterisk from another string starting with **luja** in short I wanted the starting string to be changed programmatically

I tried below code, but it counts any asterisk even if **foo** is not at the beginning

```
preg_match_all('/(^foo\*)*(\*)/', '*foo*arbaz*luj*abaz*lewis*bazbazlewbaz');
```

the result is **6**. but in this case, I wanted it to fail since **foo** is not at the beginning.

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: it should only count when foo is at the beginning of the string

Comment: Why a regex ? : `if ( strpos($str, 'foo') === 0 ) echo substr_count($str, '*');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the best application for a regex, but you can use

```
preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A)|^foo)[^*]*\K\*~', $string, $matches)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0KxCy8/1). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|^foo)` - either the end of the previous successful match or `foo` at the start of string
- `[^*]*` - zero or more chars other than `*`
- `\K` - discard the text matched so far
- `\*` - an asterisk.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/pH4GE):

```php
$string = "foo*arbaz*luj*abaz*lewis*bazbazlewbaz";
echo preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A)|^foo)[^*]*\K\*~', $string, $matches);
// => 5
```

Without a regex, you could simply check if `foo` appears at the start of string (using [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)) and then use [`substr_count`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) to count the occurrences of asterisks:

```php
$string = "foo*arbaz*luj*abaz*lewis*bazbazlewbaz";
if (strpos($string, "foo") === 0 ) {
    echo substr_count($string, "*");
}
```

See [this PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/fjZN1).

Comment: Use always a strict comparison with `strpos` and 0, otherwise your condition will be `true` when `foo` isn't in the string.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks for noticing, I should have been more careful when reading the [*Warning* section](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).